# Explaining the signs of given solution using fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Assume that $y=f_1(t)$ and $y=f_2(t)$ are two solutions of the following function:
$$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d t}=\mathrm e^{t^3}- \mathrm e^{t^4}$$
and $f_1(0)>f_2(0)$. How can I describe the signs in $f_2(1)-f_1(1)$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus? I have no clue where to start.

Comment: If two functions have the same derivative, the difference of the two functions is…

Comment: @egreg: You should make this an answer, despite its shortness. I cannot improve it!

Comment: @studyhenry Did you get the solution for the sign?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $f_1'(t)=f_2'(t)$. So the difference
$$
g(t)=f_1(t)-f_2(t)
$$
has zero derivative and so it is …

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, IMO, $f_1$ and $f_2$ aren't same since $f_1(0) > f_2(0)$. I think the answer lies somewhere by using the FTC. Still researching myself...

Comment: @studyhenry Yes, they aren't the same, but the difference is constant.